# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Oct ' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(Date_of_contract AS varchar(38)), 1, 4) = 2017
```

But all I get is this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Oct ' to data type int.

Datatype for `Date_of_contract` column is `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't cast the datetime to a string and try and extract the year.

Just use

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
where YEAR(Date_of_contract) = 2017
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
where Date_of_contract >= '20170101' AND Date_of_contract < '20180101'
```

The second one is preferable if there is an index on the column as the first one is not sargable.